# how to go to previous page after some time delay in jsf

Tags: jsf

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goBack(){
setTimeout(function previous()
 { location.href="/dataprod/application/myprofile/profile_contactus.faces";
 }, 3000);  
}

</script>
<html>
<h:commandButton value="Send Mail to dataprod.com"
   action="#{ContactUs.sendMail}" styleClass="button" onClick="goBack()"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton value="Send Mail to dataprod.com"
    action="#{ContactUs.sendMail}" styleClass="button" 
    onclick="setTimeout('history.go(-1)', 3000);"/>
```

Comment: hi acttually it is going to initial page but i want go back to previous here i m displaying a success page after sending a mail after displaying that success page it must go back to mail sending page. plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Put a meta refresh header in the HTML head of the result page.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;url=profile_contactus.faces" />
```

It will go to `profile_contactus.faces` after 3 seconds.